# jQuery click event not working from php listing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a story uploading system on my webpage, which uploads stories in a specified folder, and from that it lists their content to the webpage. I made a split, so only 300 chars are shown of the text, when the user clicks it, the rest of it is shown.

Here is my code:

This one lists it:

```
<?php foreach($dataArray as $data) { ?>
    <div class="visible">
        <?php echo $data[0]; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <?php echo $data[1]; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.hidden').css('display', 'none');
$('.visible').click(function () {

    $('.hidden').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

This page('tortenetek.php') is ajaxed to the main page ('blog.php'). I included Jquery in blog.php like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stilus.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tinybox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ajax.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="../js/lightbox.js"></script>
                <script src="../js/story.js"></script>
```

Story.js is the script file i'm using.

Thanks folks!

Comment: Try this: `$('.visible').on('click', function () {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach event to dynamically added elements.
Change it to

```
$('.visible').on('click',function () {
     $('.hidden').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

Comment: Sadly it's still not working this way either. I tried to make a <a with a classname of show_story to do the trick, still nothing and besides it displays the <a> two times. Once at the top of the content and once at the bottom. Any ideas? This is my code for the <a> :  <div class="visible">
        <?php echo $data[0] . "<br/><center><a href='#' class='story_show'>Teljes Történet</a></center>"; ?>
    </div>

Comment: @trisztann: Can you please explain this bit more? I think we were talking about `click` event and now you are talking something different.

Comment: The click event is now linked to a link, clicking that link still doesn't work to show the full story. I used the .on('click' .. ) event.