# Jquery Event not initiating on php echo

Tags: jquery

Well I have this certain code that echo a list of containers,

Here's a **sample** code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_recipe; $i++) {

<div class='scrollButtons'>
    <a>
        <img class='leftAlign btnUp' id='imgScrollUp". $i ."' src='/skin/frontend/default/default/images/scroll-up-inactive.gif'>
    </a>

    <a>
        <img class='rightAlign btnDown' id='imgScrollDown". $i ."' src='/skin/frontend/default/default/images/scroll-down-active.gif'>
    </a>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>

}
```

Then for example, I want to click the image class of **btnDown**

Here's my jquery code

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function($j) {

  $j('.btnDown').on('click', function () {
       alert('WUZZAAAAAH!!');
  });

});
```

It doesn't even alert, any solution for this problem?

Here's the questions that I've seen but, never worked.

[jQuery click event not working from php listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317435/jquery-click-event-not-working-from-php-listing)

[jQuery not working when I echo it from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530894/jquery-not-working-when-i-echo-it-from-php)

Comment: whether the elements are loaded dynamically

Comment: can you try `$(document).on('click', '.btnDown', function(){alert('WUZZAAAAAH!!');})`

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: can you share us your site url? I can help you to look through

Comment: looks fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gEpR3/1/ check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: Ummm, it doesn't have any errors on the jsfiddle that you sent. It worked perfectly fine. D:
Regarding the site, it does not even show any errors on the console. can't give. :/

Comment: can you run `$j('.btnDown').length` in your console... and see what is returned

Comment: Hello there, it says 12. So, reason behind why it's 12 because I have 12 button images that has a class of btnDown.

Comment: Take a bet, can you remove both the 'id' temporary and try again?

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no class `btnDown` in your html above.
2. How are you looping through html without any `<?php` , `?>` separators?